# python implementation of the function T32_GetBreakpointList

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

We are trying to write a python script for lauterbach where we try to get in a variable the address of the breakpoints set without address like, t32api.T32_Cmd("Break.Set func+4") or t32api.T32_Cmd("Break.Set func\0+4").

We identified the function, T32_GetBreakpointList to get the address of the list of breakpoints. We are not able to create a python version of the T32_GetBreakpointList

Comment: Can you explain in detail which problem you're having? Can you post the code which is not working?

Comment: Also it's better to use `T32_QueryBreakpointObjCount` and `T32_ReadBreakpointObjByIndex`. The "Obj" functions support more breakpoint properties.